# How to analyze HTML Page using PHP?

Tags: php, html

Hi I want to analyze HTML page by following example.

1. I can put url page to textfield then press enter.
2. I get some text from HTML page such as title, h1, div id="do" or so on.

How I can do it by using PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: See this question on how to parse HTML using PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Answer (score 2):

With [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or the like and an [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Don't use file_get_contents. According to this benchmark cURL is quite a bit faster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Answer (score 1):

You want to use PHP's [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions, [here's a quick tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use file_get_contents or cURL, then use the explode functions to get data from the tags if using file_get_contents OR use "regex" for the particular html tag for getting the data

Comment: Using explode would get very messy as HTML is hardly ever perfectly written.